# Unable to start first template on Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

So I'm fairly new to Linux and truly have no idea what I am doing half of the time I do something however I started attempting to use quickly to see if I can make a little note taking program for classes. The issue is after getting quickly I cannot seem to run it.

I can get:

```
Usage:
    quickly [OPTIONS] command ...

Options:
    -t, --template <template>  Template to use if it differs from default
                               project template
    --staging                  Target launchpad staging server
    --verbose                  Verbose mode
    -h, --help                 Show help information

Commands:
    create <template> <project-name> (template is mandatory for this command)
    quickly <template-origin> <template-dest> to create a create derived template
    getstarted to get some starting hints

Examples:
    quickly create ubuntu-application foobar
    quickly push 'awesome new comment system'
    quickly -t cool-template push 'awesome new comment system'
```

However beyond this seems to be unavailable. I have tried:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application mybrowser
```

but get:

```
ERROR: No create command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to get this up and running or any alternatives which would be fitting.